# Does HTTP offer means for a website to provide information on its native language?

Tags: http, internationalization

`HTTP_ACCEPTED_LANGUAGE` allows a browser setting to determine the preferred language a website is displayed in (which can lead to some [uncomfortable user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24648/7228) do to mixed-language display when a framework is translated but the contents are not, or when it's only a bad auto-translation). I was hoping there was [a way to display websites preferably in their native language if it is among my preferred languages](https://superuser.com/q/461444/35237), but there is a requirement I don't know whether it exists:

Can a browser be informed about a website's native language via HTTP? (Using the TLD, or worse, geolocation, doesn't count since that can be wrong especially for individual user-sites)

Comment: There is a Content-Language header in the spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14 paragraph 14.12. Suppose the header is delivered, how should the browser respond? Hide content? Inform?

Comment: @rene Compare that with the languages the user set up as preferred languages, if it is among them send it as `HTTP_ACCEPTED_LANGUAGE` (re-requesting the site) and only if not send the actual most-preferred language (i.e. only see a potentially translated website if the user made clear that they won't understand the native version)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about **browser**, the answer is yes. Just set the Content-language header on the server side and browser will know the language. The problem is, I don't think it will give you anything.

But you seem to be asking what is the real language of automatically translated web page. No, there is no such thing. And personally, I don't think it should be. I understand your problem, but there is no way to create idiot-proof protocol. The universe will just make better idiots.
That said, using automatic translation on the web site as **default** rather than optional is one of the most stupid ideas I've ever seen. Personally, I would not even attempt to use such web sites.

Comment: I like the statement "The universe will just make better idiots". Sad but true...

Comment: Considering automatic translation as default being stupid, the folks at ux.se [agree](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24648/7228). Too bad some webmasters seem to be oblivious to the issue (which may of course also be due to a un-sophisticated default setting in the framework they use)

Comment: Could `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` be omitted in the request to force the server into "revealing" a site's native language? Or is that an invalid request then?

Comment: @Tobias: It has to be optional :) It was not defined for HTTP/1.0, therefore for compatibility reasons servers should expect that no Accept-Language be present. This is theory part. In reality many people take it for granted and parse this header's contents anyway.

Comment: So can't I send a request without it first such that the server has no choice but not translating (assuming it doesn't use geolocation to screw my day) and then I can check the [Content-language header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14) if given to re-request if I don't understand that language?